# Node.js list files under directory using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

On server side:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var fs = require('fs');

var images = fs.readdirSync('./images/');
var videos = fs.readdirSync('./videos/');

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {
    images: images,  // I want to pass this list of images to jade file
    videos: videos
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

index.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
  h1= images
```

And it renders nothing. Apparently, the `images` parameter hasn't been passed to the jade file. How can I get somthing like:

```
<img src="1.png" />
<img src="2.png" />
```

Comment: What is your file structure? Make sure `images` and `videos` are being set.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, but if you aren't seeing any output this means your images variable is a fasly value.

Make sure your './images/' folder exists, and is accessible to your node process.